# flutter convert ImageProvider to file

Tags: flutter

I need to convert ImageProvider to a file. What do I need to do?

I tried using the following method, but it was not ideal.

```
          if (imageProvider.runtimeType == AssetImage) {
            AssetImage assetImage = imageProvider as AssetImage;
            await rootBundle.load(assetImage.assetName);
          } else if (imageProvider.runtimeType == FileImage) {
            FileImage fileImage = imageProvider as FileImage;
            File file = fileImage.file;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check *imageProvider.runtimeType* you must pass this as argument.

So instead *imageProvider* to *imageProvider.runtimeType*

```
if (imageProvider.runtimeType == AssetImage) {
  AssetImage assetImage = imageProvider.runtimeType as AssetImage;
  await rootBundle.load(assetImage.assetName);
} else if (imageProvider.runtimeType == FileImage) {
  FileImage fileImage = imageProvider.runtimeType as FileImage;
  File file = fileImage.file;
}
```